# Openoffice headless

Tags: package-management, openoffice.org

I want to install Openoffice headless in Ubuntu 14.04. I previously successfully installed it Ubuntu 13.04 using following commands:

http://www.openvpms.org/documentation/install-openoffice-headless-service-ubuntu

But in Ubuntu 14.04 when I try to install Openoffice headless, it says that there is no package called openoffice headless. Can anyone help me with this?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Since Ubuntu now uses Libreoffice you might wanna search their documentation and according to that edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the site](http://www.openvpms.org/), OpenVPMS stands for `Open Veterinary Practice Management Software`.  Currently there is no package in a supported version of Ubuntu that specifies openoffice or libreoffice for headless operation.  At the Askbot site for libreoffice, [a question there](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/22224/libreoffice-41-headless-centos-64/) refers you back to [a command-line usage logged at commandlinefu.com instead](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11692/commandline-document-conversion-with-libreoffice).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to use open office headless as a service for one of my project. previously I managed to do that by the above link.

Comment: @Charith According to the package search run [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openoffice.org-headless), there is no version of that package `openoffice.org-headless` in the Ubuntu archives stretching back to Lucid Lynx in 2010.